# How to configure Blackberry sync operation to not delete older calendar entries in Outlook?

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, blackberry

A user upgraded his Blackberry to a Bold 9650 and now when he syncs it to Outlook 2007 his calendar entries older than 6 months old are being deleted.

There don't appear to be any settings to set to prevent this from happening.

How to stop this behavior? He wants to keep his calendar entries for as long as he can in both devices.

Sync software is Blackberry Desktop software 6.0 bundle 3084 and this didn't happen with his older BB device.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be a setting in the phones calendar retention setting on the phone itself. The phone was set to only retain the last 60 days worth of calendar entries. Setting the retention setting to "Forever" prevented it from both deleting the old calendar entries in the phone and from deleting the entries in Outlook during the sync operation via the Blackberry Desktop software.

The old Blackberry phone did not cause old entries to be deleted in Outlook during sync.